# How do I display data from SQL database in a JTable adhering to MVC?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So, I am trying to populate a JTable with data from a database. There are lots of information about this on the web, both on youtube and here on SO. My problem however is that all solutions I can find write all the code in the view Class (swing application), which is something I am not allowed to do (school assignment).

My problem is that I cant divide up the code according to MVC and still have it function.  My method for getting a specific student from my database is this:

```
public Student getOneSpecificStudent(int studentID) throws SQLException {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;

    try {
        con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        stm = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE studentID = 
        ?");
        stm.setInt(1, studentID);

        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

        Student student = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            student = new Student(rs.getInt("studentID"), 
rs.getString("studentSSN"), rs.getString("studentName"), 
rs.getString("studentAddress"), rs.getString("studentPhoneNumber"));

        }
        return student;
    } finally {
        DbUtils.close(con);
        DbUtils.close(stm);
    }
}
```

and my Controller method is this:

```
public Student getOneSpecificStudent(int studentID) throws SQLException {
    Student student = tmpDAL.getOneSpecificStudent(studentID);
    return student;

}
```

But how do I know display this in a Jtable? I have used an Object [] with already filled in data before, but this leaves me stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: I would also recommend having a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for a better way to manage your database resources

Comment: See [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step by step example on how to create a custom TableModel for a given Object.

Answer (score 1):

Since Swing already supports MVC (in a round-about way), you should start with a [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) to wrap your existing data in.

The data from the database is already modelled in the `Student` class, which is a good place to start, you simply now need to build a `TableModel` which wraps around it.  You should start by looking at [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Starting with a basic concept of a `Student`

```
public interface Student {
    public int getID();
    public String getSSN();
    public String getName();
    public String getAddress();
    public String getPhoneNumber();
}
```

We can then devise a `TableModel` which can be used to support it...

```
public class StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    protected static final String COLUMN_NAMES[] = {
        "ID", "Number", "Name", "Address", "Phone Number"
    };

    private List<Student> students;

    public StudentTableModel(List<Student> students) {
        // Prevent possible external mutation
        this.students = new ArrayList<>(students);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return students.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return Integer.class;
            default: return String.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Student student = students.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return student.getID();
            case 1: return student.getSSN();
            case 2: return student.getName();
            case 3: return student.getAddress();
            case 4: return student.getPhoneNumber();
        }
    }

}
```

This is a non-mutable model, I'll leave you to figure out how to add mutable functionality.

So, in your view, you would use the controller to get one or more `Student`s...

```
Student student = controller.getOneSpecificStudent(1);
```

You'd then create a model for the student...

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(student);
TableModel model = StudentTableModel(students);
```

And then apply it to your view...

```
someInstanceOfJTable.setModel(model);
```

Now.  If required, you could have the controller return a `StudentTableModel`, but I, personally, think this is beyond the scope of the controller, as it should not be dictating display terms to the view, that's not it's responsibility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has helped. However, when I try to create the model for the student, precisely "TableModel model = StudentTableModel (students):" I get "The method StudentTableModel(List<Student>) is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}" Why?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to pass an instance of `ActionListener` to the `StudentTableModel` instead of an instance of `List`